# CodeWars задача 8 kyu

Tags: python

не пойму почему мое решение не проходит 4 тест "AB", "Ab" ,
сама задача: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

решение:

```
def is_opposite(s1,s2):
    a = sorted(set(s1))
    b = sorted(set(s2))
    if a == b:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Comment: Вы задание то читали? Где у вас проверка, что регистр букв различается? И при чём тут сортировка и множества? Ну либо вы вообще не тот код запостили, либо не то задание.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Предположу, что вы неправильно поняли суть задания. Перечитайте его ещё раз. Вам надо выполнить проверку на регистр букв. В этом вам может помочь функция swapcase() (делает строчные буквы прописными, а прописные - строчными).

Ниже прилагаю код работающей функции:

```
def is_opposite(s1: str, s2: str)-> bool:
    if s1 == s2 == "":
        return False
    return s1 == s2.swapcase()
```

Проходит следующие проверки:

```
assert is_opposite("ab", "AB") == True
assert is_opposite("aB", "Ab") == True
assert is_opposite("aBcd", "AbCD") == True
assert is_opposite("AB", "Ab") == False
assert is_opposite("", "") == False
```

Comment: Надо же, я даже не знал, что есть такая функция. Но вообще не надо бы за людей решать задачи. Ну, кроме случаев, когда они почти решили, но застопорились на чём-то.

Comment: Думаю, в этом случае то, что я привёл код решения для человека, задавшего вопрос, некритично. Задач на кодварсе ещё много. А вот данный код может натолкнуть его на мысли о тайп хинтах и различных возможностях писать код покороче.

Comment: спасибо большое! не знал о swapcase

Comment: Так-то можно и еще подсократить код без ухудшения читабельности :) `return not (s1 == s2 == "") and (s1 == s2.swapcase())`

Comment: @АлексейР Не думаю, что `not` в начале сложного выражения, относящийся только к его части, добавляет читабельности коду, вариант с заградительным условием в начале функции гораздо проще понять )